# Change Object From Another Class

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a class which is not Activity and an Activity.
I have an onClick method and I want to pass from this onClick method an Object to the Activity.
I can't use PutExtra because of this:
MainActivity, Favorites, YtAdapter

I'm opening the Favroties class from MainActivity, but need to send from YtAdapter to Favorites.
Hope this is understandable.

YtAdapter:

```
    @Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder mHolder;
    if(convertView != null){
        mHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }else{
        mHolder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_video_item,null);
        mHolder.mVideoThumbnail = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.video_thumbnail);
        mHolder.mVideoTitle = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.video_title);
        mHolder.mVideoFavorite = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.video_favorite);

        convertView.setTag(mHolder);
    }
    //Setting the data
    final SearchResult result = mVideoList.get(position);
    mHolder.mVideoTitle.setText(result.getSnippet().getTitle());

    //Loading the image
    Picasso.with(mActivity).load(result.getSnippet().getThumbnails().getMedium().getUrl()).into(mHolder.mVideoThumbnail);

    //OnClickListeners
    mHolder.mVideoFavorite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            // Need to send SearchResult result from here to favorites //
            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            AppUtils.showToast(result.getSnippet().getTitle() + " Was added to favorites.");
        }
    });

    mHolder.mVideoThumbnail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AppUtils.showToast("Please click on title to start video");
        }
    });
    return  convertView;
}
```

Creating the YtAdapter:

```
    @Override
public void completedRequest(Object... objects){
    //Dismiss the dialog
    if(mLoadingDialog != null && mLoadingDialog.isShowing())
        mLoadingDialog.dismiss();

    //Parse the response based on type of request
    Integer reqCode = (Integer) objects[0];
    if(reqCode == null || reqCode == 0)
        throw  new NullPointerException("Request Code's value is Invalid.");
    switch (reqCode){
        case SEARCH_VIDEO:
            if(mYtadapter == null){
                mYtadapter = new YtAdapter(this);
                mYtadapter.setmVideoList((List<SearchResult>)objects[1]);
                mVideoLsv.setAdapter(mYtadapter);
            }else{
                mYtadapter.setmVideoList((List<SearchResult>) objects[1]);
                mYtadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In YtAdapter constructor you are passing Activity context and using it as mActivity in YtAdapter.

If your SearchResult is Parcelable(or Serializable), you could have,

```
public void onClick(View v) {
   Intent i=new Intent(mActivity, Favorites.class);
   i.putExtra("searchresult", result);
   mActivity.startActivity(i);
}
```

And in Favorites, you could use getIntent().getParcelableExtra("searchresult") or getIntent().getSerializableExtra("searchresult") to fetch your SearchResult object.

Let me know if you are looking for something else here!

Comment: Thanks, it's too late for me to test it now, I will test tomarrow and update.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying it now, I passed String[] with the 3 values I need, How can I use them now in the Favorites.class?

Comment: In your Favorite activity's onCreate(...) or any other callback as per your requirement, you can use following String[] arrExtra=getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("your_extra_key");

Comment: Thanks , I did it ( I did it with 3 Strings instead of a array, it was more clear to me ) But I always get Null .. I think I'm sending the Strings to MainActivity (mActivity in the code) instead of Favorites..

Comment: Aren't you using Intent i=new Intent(mActivity, Favorites.class) ?? If yes, then you must be sending your extras from MainActivity -> Favorites activity. Please put break point or log values as you send before startActivity(..) and inside say onCreate(..) of Favorite activity to find out where is the issue.

Comment: Yes, I'm sending from MainActivity but I need to send from YtAdapter. YtAdapter is not an Activity so I can't figure out how to do it...

Comment: Ok... 
1) You are creating instance of YtAdapter in MainActivity using mYtadapter = new YtAdapter(this);
2) In YtAdapter, you have mActivity getting Context from YtAdapter constructor. In your case you could configure your YtAdapter constructor as YtAdapter(MainActivity activity) but I believe for calling startActivity, YtAdapter(Context activity) is enough.
3) Inside onClick of your ImageView you have in getView(), get values you need to send and put as extra in Intent
4) In onCreate or such callbacks, use getIntent().getStringExtra() to get your value.
Pls let me know if I missed something

Comment: First of all, Thanks for all the help and patience! I pretty much have what you worte, but I just need to know how to make the line:                 Intent intent = new Intent(YYY, Favorites.class); YYY should be YtAdapter. I tried with context but It's doing problem in MainActivity.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a reference of the activity to the YtAdapter so you can access public methods that are contained in the activity class.

**EDIT:**

You have the line `mYtadapter = new YtAdapter(this);`.  If `this` is not the activity you want to reference, you can change the constructor of the YtAdapter class to include an activity.  For example:

`public YtAdapter(Activity myActivity) { ... }`

You should read up on object oriented basics

Comment: Could you please give me an example? I tried to do something like Favorites favorites = new Favorites(); and then favorites.X = result. but it didn't work ..

Comment: Post the code where you create the YtAdapter object

Comment: Thanks, it's too late for me to test it now, I will test tomarrow and update.